# How would I interpret not exists in this particular query in combination with the except statement?

Tags: sql

**SCHEMA**

**Nurse** ( nid , nname , age , salary , sid ) 
**Supervisor** ( sid , rating ) 
**WorksIn** ( nid , hid  , hours  ) 
**Hospital** ( hid  , hname , tid  )
**Town** ( tid  , tname , mayor )

Hi this is the schema for the particualr question I am going to ask?

Question: what does this query produces?

http://imageshack.com/a/img585/5827/5bw7.png

```
SELECT nname
FROM Nurse N
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (  (SELECT    H.hid
        FROM      Hospital H
        WHERE     H.token = 'Toronto')
     EXCEPT
       (SELECT    W.hid
        FROM      WorksIn W
        WHERE     N.nid = W.nid)
```

Solution so far: So far I have reached upon the conclusion that the nested select  statements combine to give out the hospital ids in Toronto with no working nurses.I am not sure how the not exists is going to have an effect on that. is the solution all working nurses in Toronto ? or just all working nurses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query is the names of all nurses who work in every hospital in Toronto.

---

Explanation:

```
 SELECT H.hid FROM Hospital H WHERE H.town = 'Toronto'
```

are the ids of hospitals in Toronto.

```
 SELECT W.hid FROM WorksIn W WHERE N.nid = W.nid
```

are the ids of hospitals the nurse `N.nid` works in.

```
 SELECT H.hid FROM Hospital H WHERE H.town = 'Toronto'
 EXCEPT
 SELECT W.hid FROM WorksIn W WHERE N.nid = W.nid
```

are the hospitals in Toronto the nurse `N.nid` doesn't work in.

Thus

```
 SELECT nname
 FROM Nurse N
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT H.hid FROM Hospital H WHERE H.town = 'Toronto'
     EXCEPT
     SELECT W.hid FROM WorksIn W WHERE N.nid = W.nid
 )
```

are the names of nurses who don't have any hospitals in Toronto they don't work in.